# Search through directory for items with multiple criteria

Tags: python, list, directory, iteration

I'm trying to write some code that searches through a directory and pulls out all the items that start with a certain numbers (defined by a list) and that end with '.labels.txt'. This is what I have so far.

```
lbldir = '/musc.repo/Data/shared/my_labeled_images/labeled_image_maps/'

picnum = []
for ii in os.listdir(picdir):
   num = ii.rstrip('.png')
   picnum.append(num)

lblpath = []   
for file in os.listdir(lbldir):
   if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.labels.txt') and fnmatch.fnmatch(file, ii in picnum + '.*'):
       lblpath.append(os.path.abspath(file))
```

Here is the error I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a03c65e65a71> in <module>()
  3 lblpath = []
  4 for file in os.listdir(lbldir):
----> 5     if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.labels.txt') and fnmatch.fnmatch(file, ii in picnum + '.*'):
  6         lblpath.append(os.path.abspath(file))

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I realize the ii in picnum part won't work but I don't know how to get around it. Can this be accomplished with the fnmatch module or do I need regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes because you are trying to add `".*"` (a string) to the end of `picnum`, which is a list, and not a string.

Also, `ii in picnum` isn't giving you back each item of `picnum`, because you are not iterating over `ii`. It just has the last value that it was assigned in your first loop.

Instead of testing both at once with the `and`, you might have a nested test that operates when you find a file matching `.labels.txt`, as below. This uses `re` instead of `fnmatch` to extract the digits from the beginning of the file name, instead of trying to match each `picnum`. This replaces your second loop:

```
import re
for file in os.listdir(lbldir):
    if file.endswith('.labels.txt')
        startnum=re.match("\d+",file)
        if startnum and startnum.group(0) in picnum:
            lblpath.append(os.path.abspath(file))
```

I think that should work, but it is obviously untested without your actual file names.